# Mocking HttpContextBase with Microsoft Fakes - UserGet property is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking

I am currently trying to write some unit tests utilizing the Microsoft Fakes Framework. For a specific unit test I have to mock the Controller.User property. So I added a fake assembly for System.Web and created a new instance of System.Fakes.StubHttpContextBase:

```
var stubHttpContext = new System.Web.Fakes.StubHttpContextBase();
```

In a next step I would like to set the return value for the User property. I expected to find a "UserGet" property on my StubHttpContextBase instance but no luck:

[image: No UserGet property available]

What really confuses me is that MS Fakes is able to generate getters for every other property except the "User" property. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Look at http://www.richonsoftware.com/post/2012/05/02/Noninvasive-Unit-Testing-in-ASPNET-MVC-A-Microsoft-Fakes-Deep-Dive.aspx. May be you need shim instead of stub?

Answer (score 2):

```
var child = new StubHttpContextBase();
var basecontext=  new ShimHttpContextBase(child) 
    {
        UserGet= () =>   
            new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("mhu"), new string[0]) 
    };

var conCntx = new ControllerContext();
conCntx.HttpContext = basecontext;
controllerUnderTest.ControllerContext = conCntx;
```